# RAM with different CAS Latencies?

Tags: laptop, memory

If I have 2 RAM chips that are similar in every way except their CAS latencies, will this cause problems in a HP ENVY 17-j184nr?

For instance this RAM chip used with the default RAM chip: [https://www.amazon.com/Eluktro-Performance-PC3-12800-204-Pin-Laptops/dp/B00O71DO92/ref=cm_cd_al_qh_dp_t](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00O71DO92)

&

Default Chipset: http://support.hp.com/us-en/product/HP-ENVY-17-j100-Notebook-PC-series/5401174/model/6875780/document/c04126410/

Comment: Just a comment on your choice of RAM modules here, for your laptop the one you have linked is quite expensive for a 8GB module... for $30 less you can get a single 8GB from a reputable manufacturer like Crucial or G.Skill, or for the same price you could get a higher performance matched set for dual-channel mode like https://www.amazon.com/Crucial-PC3-14900-SODIMM-204-Pin-Memory/dp/B00JCRZ6XS as an example (we do NOT recommend specific products here, it's just an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it shouldn't not cause any issue, the slower CAS 11 speed of the original RAM chip will prevail and both modules will run with a CAS value of 11 (assuming everything else is equal). When mixing RAM, the lower specs prevail in almost every case. Using mixed RAM will force the system to run in single-channel mode.

Note that the HM87 chipset in your laptop does support dual-channel mode when using matched RAM modules, which can give performance improvements in some cases, so it might be worth it to research a matched module to what you have installed already (search the part number on eBay, you can often find modules from parted out machines at very low cost).