# My CPU memory speed reduces to 2400 when adding another module of 2666

Tags: windows, memory, dual-channel, dram, cpu-z

I already have a RAM module which came with the actual laptop.
This was an 8GB module with clock speed of 2666.
I purchased one more of the same speed and capacit. This runs in dual channel mode but brings down the memory speed to 2400.

Here are some screenshots from CPU-Z.

What am I doing wrong that the speed reduces? Are the RAMs not compatible?

[image: memory]

[image: slot1]

[image: slot2]

[image: Task manager]

Comment: when OC'ing RAM, its always best to get all your sticks from the same package. I just upgraded a box from 16 -> 32GB, and bought the exact same model of chips that I already had for the second 16GB. but now I can't OC to 4133 as I had previously done. now it runs at 2133 (the highest non-XMP SPD profile available) and it appears there is nothing I can do about it, except shell out to rebuy the RAM I already have.

Comment: Your modules are essentially forcing your memory controller to negotiate a common set of timings that both modules support, one module only supports CAS 17 at 1236 while and CAS 18 at 1333MHz, the other supports CAS 17 at 1333 so they fall back to the highest supported by both. This is why people recommend getting identical sticks, preferably from the same batch to make sure that you don't get newer modules with different timings.

Comment: @Mokubai You should turn that into an answer. We may have the beginnings of a canonical question answer here which can be used as a dupe target ...

Comment: @DavidPostill I was looking for a duplicate, but all I can find is "it don't work" questions. Going to write an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your memory has different timings for the memory modules.

One module can work at a higher frequency with a higher CAS latency, while the other module can only work at that CAS latency at a lower frequency. One module only supports CAS 17 at 1333 while the other works at CAS 19 at 1333MHz. In order to operate both modules at CAS 17 one module is needing to drop its clock speed.

The result is that the memory controller in your CPU effectively negotiates down the frequency until it finds a set of memory latencies that will work together. In your case this point is apparently 1200MHz (2400 DDR).

This is why people recommend getting identical sticks, preferably from the same batch to make sure that you don't get newer modules with different timings. Memory manufacturers can change specifications at any time without warning and you may end up with a "better" nearly identical stick that causes this kind of memory incompatibility.

Some references for [mixing CAS latencies](https://superuser.com/search?q=CAS%20latency)

- [Memory: trading off CAS latency versus speed](https://superuser.com/questions/67298/memory-trading-off-cas-latency-versus-speed)
- [RAM with different CAS Latencies?](https://superuser.com/questions/1185444/ram-with-different-cas-latencies)
- [Mixing RAM sticks with different CAS Latency and timings?](https://superuser.com/questions/1226768/mixing-ram-sticks-with-different-cas-latency-and-timings)

Many people actively have trouble with different modules.

In some cases, and from experience, buying higher frequency memory modules can mean better compatibility with the top speeds of lower frequency modules, as they have more potential for overlap in latencies.

Comment: Thanks Mokubai for the answer. Is upgrading the older stick the new one(slot 2) a recommended  option from a performance point of view?

Comment: Honestly, unless you care about maybe a couple of percentage points improvement in games I would not really worry. You are not on the bleeding edge of performance and chances are going from single-channel (1 DIMM) at 2666 to dual-channel (2 DIMMS) at 2400 is going to have been a boost already. You might see a minor improvement in some situations but you've already gotten the bigger boost by doubling RAM bandwidth (dual channel minus approx 10% frequency drop) IMO.

Comment: great. thanks again @Mokubai. it helped me a lot. Still one question which is troubling me. Out of curiosity, what should have been the CAS Latency i should have gone for to get 2666 compatibility to the RAM in slot#1? One of 19/20 riight?

Comment: It looks like you should have been aiming for CAS 19 RAM, but it could also have been one of the other timings that drove the frequency down. Modules can be wildly different and are a minefield due to the limited space in the EEPROM used to tell the system what the module supports.

Comment: thank you @Mokubai